Trying to get in game cursor to move smoothly
I am trying to move a cursor object in the game using Input Actions. and for some reason it ends before it stops moving if I use Time.DeltaTime to move it smoothly. But when I remove it it works perfectly but is instant which isn't what I want.
*edit changed the code to below. and i now have the y elevation working just need to fix the issue of it not moving smoothly. i tried changing the call condition but still had the same results sadly. not sure what to do but im open to suggestions.
public class cursor : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] float speed = 1f;
    public float height;
    RaycastHit hit;  

    [SerializeField] LayerMask terrainLayerMask;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask obstacleLayer;

    void Update()
    {
      Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, -Vector3.up);
      Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.down * height, Color.yellow);
      

      if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
      {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "terrain")
        {
          Debug.Log(hit.point.y);
          var position = transform.position;
          
          position.y = hit.point.y +3.5f;
          transform.position = position;
        }
      }
    }
    
   public void OnCursorLeft(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.performed == true)
    {
        var position = transform.position;
        position.z += 2;
        transform.position = position;
        

        if(transform.position.z > 32)
        {
            position.z = 32;
            transform.position = position;
        }
       
    }
  }

    public void OnCursorRight(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.performed == true)
    {
       
        var position = transform.position;
        position.z -= 2;
        transform.position = position;
        position.y = hit.point.y +3.5f;

        if(transform.position.z <= 0)
        {
            position.z = 0;
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
  }

    public void OnCursorUp(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.performed == true)
    {
        var position = transform.position;
        position.x += 2;
        transform.position = position;

        if(transform.position.x > 32)
        {
            position.x = 32;
            transform.position = position;
        }
       
    }
  }

    public void OnCursorDown(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.performed == true)
    {
        var position = transform.position;
        position.x -= 2;
        transform.position = position;

        if(transform.position.x <= 0)
        {
            position.x = 0;
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
  }      
}


for your terrain question: you can't just use terrain.transform.position assuming your terrain isn't just plain flat. how would you know the y position at the exact point you need? is the "cursor" on a hill, is it on a gorge, who knows. therefore you have to use some form of raycast to determine the exact position your "cursor" is under

I am already using raycast for drawing a line so i could use that for figuring out the y value.

In this line
transform.position = Vector3((transform.position.x + 2, 0,0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);

you set the position on X to
x = (x + 2) * speed * Time.deltaTime

This is not a movement but rather stuck around that position as the * Time.deltaTime pretty much cancels out the + 2. For 60 frames per second Time.deltaTime is about 0.017.
What you rather want is to ADD a vector to your position and multiply the entire + part instead of the resulting position. (Basically just your placement of ( ) is wrong)
x = x + (2 * speed * Time.deltaTime)

so something like
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 2 * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

which personally I prefer to write as
transform.position += Vector3.right * 2 * speed * Time.deltaTime;


Or as you are going to manipulate the position further for your terrain height anyway you should minimize the amount of property accesses and rather work with a temporary local value
var position = transform.position;
position.x += 2 * speed * Time.deltaTime;
position.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position);
transform.position = position;

see also Terrain.SampleHeight

So I tried this and I am still having the same issue of it not moving all the way. Like x is only increasing by .08 to .1 instead of 2. but if i remove * speed * Time.deltaTime; it adds 2. like its suppose to. not sure why this is happening.

My only guess as to why it's doing that is because of context.started which only lasts like a single frame. So I wonder if I change that something else if it would work.

@NectarNoks sounds like something else is overwriting that objects position ...
